# Regex, numbers below 20k

Tags: regex, vwo

I'm looking for a regex to validate if numbers are below 20 000. 
I can't find the right solution, I have so far this:

```
(^([1-9]([0-9]{0,3})|20000)$)
```

Which works quite ok but as soon as it gets to 10 000 it gives no matches. So I have a gap from 9 999 - 20 000.

What am I doing wrong? I don't use regex for these situations, but the 3th party program required regex for such..

Thanks!

Comment: [`^([1-9]\d{0,3}|1\d{4}|20000)$`](https://regex101.com/r/tK8lM7/1).

Comment: Surely the simplest way to check is to cast it to a number and check if it is `< 20000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex - `^([1-9]([0-9]{0,3})|20000)$` - matches numbers from `1` till `9999` and `20000`.

You may use

```
^([1-9]\d{0,3}|1\d{4}|20000)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK8lM7/1)

Breakdown:

- `^` - match start of string
- `([1-9]\d{0,3}|1\d{4}|20000)` - match one of the alternatives:

  - `[1-9]\d{0,3}` - `1` to `9` followed with 0 to 3 any digits (from `1` till `9999`)
  - `1\d{4}` - `1` followed with any 4 digits (to match `10000 - 19999`)
  - `20000` - literally `20000`
- `$` - match the end of string

Comment: Thanks! I marked your answer as the correct one for the breakdown :)

Answer (score 2):

The `([1-9]([0-9]{0,3})` part is designed to match all numbers *strictly* below `2000` but you define it as: "A digit one to nine followed by zero to three digits". Now `10 000` is a one followed by four zeros: you can rewrite the part as:

```
[1-9][0-9]{3}|1[0-9]{4}
```

The full regex is now:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3}|1[0-9]{4}|20000$
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got this:

```
^([01]?\d{0,4}|20000)$
```

Which match any number from 0 to 20 000 and allow the user to use number with leading 0 <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI8oQ6/1)</kbd>